# Angular does not seem to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, rest, heroku

I'm new to Angular and experimenting a bit. I have a REST API running locally (Express app) and I have Angular code in the public folder that consumes the REST API. All code for server and client are running from one codebase and everything works fine, I can add, update, delete items in a Mongo db that is running locally (code is [here](https://github.com/wapptastic/Express_Todo_Mongo_API_Angular))

The idea is however to run the server API on Heroku and to split off the Angular code so that I have all HTML and JS file in a complete separate folder, not being part of any Express app. The server part is working good as I'm using Postman to add, update and delete items. When using the Angular UI, it seems the Angular code is not executed (cfr Screenshot)

[image: ScreenshotAngular]

The code for this is [here](https://github.com/wapptastic/Express_Angular_Standalone).

Any thoughts on why running this HTML code does not seem to work? Enabling or disabling CORS in the Chrome browser does not help.

Comment: Open console and check the error explaining the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, but it not helpful to me. It mentions a syntax error in the controller.js file right at the bottom of the file. As this is exactly the same code as in the working app, I'm not sure what is the issue:             `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)`

Comment: To add some more info: when I embed this code into a very simple Express app (basically just starting an Express app on localhost:3000 that contains the Angular code in the public folder) it works. I can then see that items get created, updated and deleted. I'm guessing this can never be the purpose of Angular...

Comment: The url to your controller file is included as controller/controller.js, so unless your controller folder is part of the public folder on your server, this will not work. I didn't understand what you meant by "have all HTML and JS file in a complete separate folder, not being part of any Express app", but adjust the url so that it points to the right folder when your server serves the html and that should solve the problem

Comment: The controller.js file is part of the controller folder.  The code for this is [here](https://github.com/wapptastic/Express_Angular_Standalone). These are only HTML/JS files that should work in my opionion, but it is not. However, when I build a small Express app around it (basically just a simple server.js file that starts a server), it works perfectly. I wanted to get it to work without the Express app around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a special character at the bottom of your **controller.js**.

```
controllers/controller.js:

$scope.updateTodo = function() {
  console.log("Completed" + $scope.todo.completed);
  $http.put(url + $scope.todo._id, $scope.todo).success(function(response) {
     console.log("new updated: " + response.updated_at);
    refresh();
    })
};

}]);ï»¿    <------- See invalid characters
```

I pulled the code locally from your GitHub repository, removed the special character, and it ran as expected. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Matt, that was indeed the problem. I have never seen these characters in my editor (Sublime Text). How could you visualize them?

Comment: @wiwa1978 I was able to see them in the Chrome developer tools. The sources tab will show you the loaded scripts. Cheers!